# jquery set focus on dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

In jquery I've appended a `<li>` element to an unordered list.

How do I focus on the newly created `<li>` ?

If I do the following:

```
$("ul").append('<li><input type="text" value="Hi!"></li>');
$("li:last").focus(); //doesn't work because new <li> isn't in dom yet
```

the focus doesn't work, as noted above.

I know jquery 1.4.2 has a `live()` event handler which allows you load event handlers to dynamically added elements, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li').live('load', function () {
       alert("hi!");
       $("li:last").focus();
    });
 });
```

Comment: The `input` element is an **EMPTY** element, it shouldn't have an end tag. You probably want to put `hi!` in a value attribute.

Comment: @David, thanks. This isn't the actual code, but I'll fix it anyway.

Comment: 2500 views and not a single upvote. GOOD TIMES.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only set the focus to elements which can hold the focus. By default a list item cannot. This is why your first example fails, not because it isn't in the DOM (it **is** in the DOM, that is what `append` does)

In general you should use elements designed to hold the focus (i.e. **set the focus on the input not the list item**). You can also (but this is less backwards compatible and less logical) use HTML5's [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) (probably setting it to `0`).

`onload` will not work because list items do not load external content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, `$(YourElement).trigger("focus")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post I know, but a simple way to solve this issue is to create a text input in your HTML and set its CSS to "display: none;". On the LI's click event, set the focus in this input and listen to its keypress events.

I've done it and it works like a charm.