# How can I scroll down to the last li item in a dynamically added ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul defined like

```
 <div>
   <ul id="mylist">
   </ul>
 </div>
```

In my javascript I add li items to this ul with jquery using

```
$("mylist").append("<li>Test</li>");
```

I want my ul to automatically scroll down the div to when I have added a lot of li items and ul surpass the height defined for it

Things I have tried:

1. In CSS I set a max-height and overflow-y:scroll for the ul
2. In Javascript I did $("mylist li").last().focus();

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2847902/3793566)?

Comment: Check this if it helps [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j5Lerrz/)

Answer (score 19):

Click this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ucD3/461/). It will help you.

Jquery:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
   $("#mylist").append("<li>Test</li>");
   $('#mylist').animate({scrollTop: $('#mylist').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
});
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <ul id="mylist"></ul>
  <button class="add">Add li</button>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#mylist {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner: `var list = $("#mylist");
$('.add').click(function(){
   list.append("<li>Test</li>").animate({scrollTop: list.prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);  
});`

Answer (score 11):

This can be done also in Vanilla JS no need for JQuery:

```
items = document.querySelectorAll(".dummy");
    last = items[items.length-1];
    last.scrollIntoView();
```

See also snippet below:

```js
//this adds the new element at the bottom
button = document.querySelector("button")
button.onclick = function() {
list = document.querySelector("#mylist");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = "Added with Vanilla JS"
list.appendChild(li);



//this jumps to the last element on the bottom
items = document.querySelectorAll(".dummy");
console.log(items);
last = items[items.length-1];
last.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
#mylist {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.dummy {
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<div>
  <ul id="mylist">
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used jQuery `animate` to function smooth scrolling. Im just adding few elements to the `ul` and then scrolling to the last `li` element under `ul`.

**JSCode:**

```
$(function () {
  $("#mylist").append("<li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li>");
  $('div').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#mylist li").last().offset().top
  },
    'slow');
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
    <ul id="mylist"></ul>
</div>
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/0Lofm4mL/1/**

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $last = $("<li>Test</li>").appendTo("#mylist");

  $("#mylist").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $last.offset().top
  }, '500', 'swing', function() {});
})
```

```css
#mylist {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.dummy {
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<div>
  <ul id="mylist">
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
    <li class="dummy">Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler answer is the following:

```js
function setItem(){
    // We go through all items and change the value of the id attribute to empty
    $('#mylist li').each(function (i, v) {
       $(v).attr('id', '');
    });

    // We add the items
    $('#mylist').append('<li id="last">test</li>');

    // Currently there is only one identifier called "last"
    window.location.href = '#last';
}
```

```css
#mylist{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="setItem();">Add</button>
<div id="mylist"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is one simple way to do this:

```
container = $('MyElement').get(0);
container.scrollTop = (container.scrollHeight + container.offsetHeight);
```